# How to upload huge data CSV file using delayed_job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@csv_import = CSVImport.new(params[:catalog_import])
```

When i upload csv with huge data,i get error of TIMEOUT.

How i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

It can process the file in batches for large files.

Here is an example for their docs with Resque and chuck sizes:

```
filename = '/tmp/some_file.csv'
options = { :chunk_size => 100 }
n = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options) do |chunk|
    Resque.enque( ResqueWorkerClass, chunk ) # pass chunks of CSV-data to Resque workers for parallel processing
end
=> returns number of chunks
```